# Mapreduce parallel copies vs http threads

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am not able get the differences between the below 2 mapreduce job configuration properties.

> mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies
>
> mapreduce.tasktracker.http.threads

The mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies is the number of parallel transfers run by reduce during the copy(shuffle) phase.

The mapreduce.tasktracker.http.threads is the number of worker threads that for the http server. This is used for map output fetching.

parallelcopies says the number of parallel transfers , I guess it referes the parallel transfers of map outputs to the reducer at a time. http threads says the number of http threads to be running in reducer to copy the map outputs.

I not able to differentiate between these 2 properties, seems identical to me since both relates to the number of fetchers of reducers.

Kindly help me in understanding the actual intend of these properties and how they would help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below picture gives you an idea about flow of mapreduce program.

After map tack the node running map task will serve the output files via HTTP threads and the number of such threads will be governed by **mapreduce.tasktracker.http.threads**. By default it is 40, means a tasktracker will fetch data by 40 http threads. So it can server for 40 reducers (minimum) at time it can go high as well.

As soon as the data is available at the map side reducer copy them from each mapper node. So a time they have to copy from many nodes. To make use of all the system resources and reduce time to copy intermediate data, reducer will do that in parallel. This number of parallel copies is governed by **mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies**. By default it is 5, so one reducer can copy from 5 map outputs in parallel.

[image]